# How to get the highest and lowest value items of an array?

Tags: php

In an array like this:

```
$array['abc'] = 10;
$array['foo'] = 90;
$array['bar'] = 0;
$array['baz'] = 50;
```

How can I retrieve the highest value item (90 in the above example) and the lowest value (0 in above example)?

Comment: Do you care about knowing what the key is for min/max?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

```
echo min(2, 3, 1, 6, 7);  // 1
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

```
echo max(1, 3, 5, 6, 7);  // 7
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 7):

with [min()](http://docs.php.net/min) / [max()](http://docs.php.net/max)

```
$array = array();
$array['abc'] = 10;
$array['foo'] = 90;
$array['bar'] = 0;
$array['baz'] = 50;

echo " min: ", min($array);
echo " max: ", max($array);
```