# How do I get the highest value when using loops?

Tags: php

I want to get the highest value of my array.
This are the two ways when I'm working with php functions.

```
$a = array(1,125,1068); 
1.  $value = max($a);  
    print_r ($value);

2.  asort($a);
    $value = end($a);
    print_r ($value);
```

I just couldn't figure out how to get the highest value when using loops.

Comment: Why do you want to use loops when max function works without them?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to find the max value using a loop? Please provide code sample or explain better

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the highest and lowest value items of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539580/how-to-get-the-highest-and-lowest-value-items-of-an-array)

Comment: I want to find the max value using a loop. I'm just looking for other ways to understand php better.

Comment: What you're trying to do will in fact teach you the wrong ways to use PHP, not "understand PHP better". If you really want to learn PHP better, browse the online documentation at php.net http://www.php.net/manual/ see what functions already exist to do what you want.

Comment: @xzyfer - Thanks for the comment. I'm working with the functions.

Comment: @kolip, no problem, the number one biggest mistake people make is not taking advantage of PHP already has to offer. Using the built-in functions will make your code faster, easier to read and maintain, and make it possible for other developers to work with and contribute to you code in the future.

Comment: @xzyfer - I understand what you mean. Reason why I was asking that I've been in trouble understanding the for-loop.

Comment: In that case jsut google a tutorial on for loops. The concepts at the same across alot of languages. The real trick is judging when to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
$highest = 0;
//if you have negative values: $highest = min($a);
foreach($a as $item){
    if ($item > $highest){
        $highest = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is `max()` why to use loop. lame answer to lame question

Comment: "I just couldn't figure out how to get the highest value when using loops." That's the answer.

Comment: start with $clone = $array;  and $highest = array_shift($clone);  then get into loop.

Answer (score 2):

Without using the max() function, you can do something like

```
<?php
$a = array(1,125,1068)
$max = $a[0];
for ($i = 1; $i <count($a); $i++) {
    if ($a[$i] > $max) {
        $max = $a[$i];
    }
}
```

echo $max;
    ?>

Comment: I'll mark it as answered asap. Thank you. This is what I needed and it helps me a lot to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

`max()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Comment: [How do I write a good answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: As you cann see I already found out how the max() works. I'm really looking for a way to do it without php funtions. But Thank you anyway.

Comment: I _strongly_ urge you to not revert the edit that I just made. LMGTFY or similar is not appropriate here. Now, would you care to summarize your link in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dd = array(50, -25, -5, 80, -40, -152, -45, 28, -455, 100, 98, -455);
$curr = '';
$max = $dd[0];

for($i = 0; $i < count($dd); $i++) {
    $curr = $dd[$i];

    if($curr >= $max) {
        $max = $curr;   
   }
}
```