# How can I find the lowest price (number) and highest price (number) in an Unordered PHP array?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the highest and lowest value items of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539580/how-to-get-the-highest-and-lowest-value-items-of-an-array)

I have an array in PHP which output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 180.99 [1] => 140 [2] => 200.45 )
```

The numbers can be decimals because they are prices.

For example, I want to show that the product has price ranging from 140 to 200 . How can I use that unordered array to find the min, max price within it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have another product array ??? If yes how does it look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like using these special functions - [**min**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [**max**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) - will be helpful, perhaps?

```
$arr = array(180.99, 140, 200.45);
$min = min($arr);
echo $min; // 140
$max = max($arr);
echo $max; // 200.45
```

Comment: Will that work with decimals also?

Comment: Obviously. If you need to show the integer parts only, just change `max($arr)` to `floor(max($arr))` (the same way minimum can be changed).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) functions as:

```
$arr = array(180, 140, 200);
$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);
```

Comment: Does that work if the numbers contain decimals.

Answer (score 1):

you can order the array, using [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), and then access the first and last element, of the sorted array.

```
   $arr = array(180, 140, 200);
   sort($arr);
   echo $arr[0]; //first element
   echo end($arr); //last element
```

you can also use, min() and max() functions like this,

```
  $arr = array(180, 140, 200);      
  echo min($arr); //min element
  echo max($arr); //max element
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly `min()` & `max()`

http://php.net/min

http://php.net/max

Answer (score 0):

`echo "this price range is between $" . min($array) . " and $" . max($array);`

do you mean `min()` and `max()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(180, 140, 200);

echo 'Min: ' . min($array) . "\n";
echo 'Max: ' . max($array) . "\n";
```